# Add noise to Audio File and Reconvert the Noisy signal using Librosa Python

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I am adding noise to a signal using librosa but after adding noise I am unable to save the signal back as wav file.

My code is as follows:

```
import librosa

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

file_path = r'path\to\file'
#
#
signal, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr = 16000)
# plt.plot(signal)
#
RMS=math.sqrt(np.mean(signal**2))

STD_n= 0.001
noise=np.random.normal(0, STD_n, signal.shape[0])
#
# # X=np.fft.rfft(noise)
# # radius,angle=to_polar(X)
#
signal_noise = signal+noise
```

I want to convert signal_noise as a wav file. I tried different librosa functions but I am unable to find one. I tried using scipy.io.wavfile.write but I was getting an error probably because Librosa generates Normalized audio while Scipy doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the `soundfile` library. Add these lines to ur code:

```
import soundfile
soundfile.write('filename.wav',signal_noise,16000)
```

Parameters:

- The 1st parameter is the file name
- The 2nd parameter is the audio that you want to save
- The 3rd parameter is the sample rate

Hope that this helps you!

Comment: Thanks a lot Sushil. That was really helpful.